# Why does an app lock up Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

There is an app. If i open up a specific file with it, Windows 7 actually locks up. I can't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and I could only move my mouse. Nothing is clickable. Nothing can be done. It reminds me of the Windows 98 days.

I don't suppose I can find out why it happens? Maybe someone already knows a way or two that causes Windows 7 to lock up?

As a programmer I am interested in how this could happen.

Answer (score 1):

Check the event log for clues (start -> `eventvwr.msc`)

The behavior you're experiencing is likely due to Windows being stuck in a driver or some other kernel facility.  Windows implements things like network drives and the GUI as kernel code, so for example, if you are accessing a network drive and there are issues with the connection this kind of thing could happen.